# React Native Expo onAuthStateChanged fails in APK

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I've implemented some basic registration/login functionality using Firebase email/password authentication. Everything works just fine on a simulator and via the Expo Go app however when I use `expo build:android` and install the apk on my android phone it seems to crash on `onAuthStateChanged` with no errors. I've tried to catch the error but getting no luck.

I've set it up as follows:

`RootNavigator.js`:

```js
export default function RootNavigator({ navigation }) {
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState();
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthenticatedUserContext);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async authenticatedUser => {
      try {
        await (authenticatedUser ? setUser(authenticatedUser) : setUser(null));
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setErrorMsg(error.message);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    });

    return unsubscribeAuth;
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
        <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Loading...</Text>
        {errorMsg && <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errorMsg}.</Text>}
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {user ? <HomeStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And on the `Login` screen I've got a simple function that logs the user in

```js
const auth = Firebase.auth();


const onLogin = async () => {
    try {
      if (email !== '' && password !== '') {
        await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error.message)
      setLoginError(error.message);
      navigation.navigate('Home')
    }
  };
```

Firebase init config

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: Constants.manifest.extra.apiKey,
  authDomain: Constants.manifest.extra.authDomain,
  projectId: Constants.manifest.extra.projectId,
  storageBucket: Constants.manifest.extra.storageBucket,
  databaseURL: Constants.manifest.extra.databaseURL,
  messagingSenderId: Constants.manifest.extra.messagingSenderId,
  appId: Constants.manifest.extra.appId
};

let Firebase;

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export default Firebase;
```

The problem is that when using the installed apk on my android I only ever see the `Loading` section of the `RootNavigator` - I've not been able to reproduce using the Expo Go app so I can't find the issue

Comment: Does it know what `auth` is? I don't see it imported

Comment: @DVN-Anakin - sorry - updated the question. `auth` imported in top of `Login` screen. Added Firebase init too

Comment: does it apply also for RootNavigator.js ?

Comment: Yeap - imported the same way. `const auth = Firebase.auth();`

Comment: I remember having the same issue once and ended up copying a one-liner from stackoweflow `useEffect(() => firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(authenticatedUser), []);`

Comment: nothing here is `async` :  `await (authenticatedUser ? setUser(authenticatedUser) : setUser(null));
`